# Web SSO CAS Server - Properly encrypt TGT and Service Tickets

Tags: session, authentication, single-sign-on, cas

I would like to develop a centralised CAS server for user session management and looking forward to implement the following architecture:

**CASAuthServer (running with Symfony2):**

*GET /login?redirectURI=:x*

- Should be authenticating the user and ensuring he has a TGT stored for his session
- Generates a service ticket for a service, which is requesting a session for this user, and redirects the user back to the service

*GET /logout*

Destroys the TGT and all according service tickets. Result: User is logged out in every application.

*GET /validateService*

Checks whether a provided service ticket is valid and returns user information (such as user id and email)

**Question:** How do I properly generate a TGT and all service tickets? Are there any encryption-standards available in this context? Or can I just use a straight forward salt-based encryption?

I appreciate any help! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

None of that encryption is required. CAS handles and generates them all for you.